# MouseListener event MouseExited doesn't work on undecorated dialog over disabled frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouselistener, jdialog

i've got some trouble with the mouseExited event.
I have one undecorated JDialog with a MouseListener, this JDialog is half over one disabled JFrame. 
The mouseExited event is fired when the mouse exit dialog and go on the desktop, but if the mouse exit dialog and go over the disabled frame the event isn't fired.
This happens only if the frame is disabled. 
And i don't know why.. Someone can help me?

Here is a fast example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MouseListenerTest {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        System.out.println("java.version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        JFrame ownerFrame = new JFrame("Hello i am the owner frame :)");
        ownerFrame.setBounds(100,100,500,500);
        ownerFrame.setVisible(true);
        ownerFrame.setEnabled(false);
        JDialog topDialog = new JDialog(ownerFrame, "Hello i am the top dialog");
        topDialog.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        topDialog.setUndecorated(true);
        final JLabel xLabel = new JLabel("I am OUT");
        xLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        topDialog.getContentPane().add(xLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        topDialog.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("I am IN");
                xLabel.setText("I am IN");
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("I am OUT");
                xLabel.setText("I am OUT");
            }});
        topDialog.setBounds(500,200,200,200);
        topDialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Decent question and MCVE. 1+ I have not heard of this problem before, but your code does reproduce it. If it were my problem, I'd peek at the source code to see if a cause is identifiable.

Comment: Ditto @HovercraftFullOfEels kudos on MCVE & replication of the result seen by both of you. Please consider raising a bug report at the [bug database](https://bugs.java.com). I'd also suggest adding `System.out.println("java.version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));` as the first line of the main method. Here it reads `java.version: 1.8.0_45`.

Comment: After some attemps i found this happening also with Frame and Dialog on top, Frame and Frame on top, JFrame and JFrame on top. If the component in front of a disabled frame is undecorated, the mouseexited event isn't fired.

Comment: *"After some attemps i found this happening also with.."* Add that detail to the bug report. And a tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 1):

> [Component#setEnabled(boolean) (Java Platform SE 8 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setEnabled-boolean-)
>   Note: **Disabling a heavyweight container prevents all components in this container from receiving any input events.** But disabling a lightweight container affects only this container.

`JFrame` is a heavyweight (top level) component, so I think that this behavior is specification.

Comment: The disabled JFrame is only a background, i want the mouseexited event be fired when the mouse exit to my undecorated frame, that is not disabled.